# Can I filter autocomplete suggestions by return type in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

When autocompleting method calls in Eclipse, is it possible to filter the list of suggestions  on these criteria :

- return type
- class implementing the method

i.e. when I type `myArrayList.` I would like to find methods returning `boolean` which are inherited from `AbstractCollection` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create a local variable and attempt to assign to it, Eclipse puts the matching return types first in the autocomplete list, e.g.

```
AbstractCollection obj;
boolean temp = obj.<autocomplete list>
```

If you declare obj as AbstractCollection, you won't see any other methods.

Comment: Nice tip for the return type, I had forgotten it. As for the class filtering, it is kind of a workaround (I would have to cast my object just to get the desired information)